# Load Images on webPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, image

I was trying to load an image on a `<asp:image>` control.

The thing is that the paths of the images are saved in the database, and some of the image names contain white spaces. For example "Image name number 2.jpg".

When I'm setting the ImageUrl attribute for the asp control, it can be assigned without any trouble, but when loaded in html the url is displayed as seen below:

```
"C:\..\..\Image%20name%20number%202.jpg"
```

Because of those "%20" it can't find the picture so it won't show.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: %20 represents a space in URLs... Can you not remove the spaces in your image names?

Comment: Best bet is definitely to rename the images. replace the white spaces with underscores or hyphens. You shouldn't be referencing the images from your C drive on your computer though.

Comment: Nope, I'm doing the web page for a System that allready exists in desktop, and if I change something on there the desktop system will crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%20` part is actually the space character. You can easily remove it by passing the URL to `decodeURI()` in javascript:

```
//fileName = "C:....\Image%20name%20number%202.jpg"
var fileName = decodeURI( fileName );
//fileName = "C:....\Image name number 2.jpg"
```

You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI

The opposite of `decodeURI()` is `encodeURI()`:

```
//fileName = "C:....\Image name number 2.jpg"
var fileName = encodeURI( fileName );
//fileName = "C:....\Image%20name%20number%202.jpg"
```

You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Answer (score 0):

The `%20` is expected to replace a `space` whenever a string is represented as a URI.
These `%20`s should not be causing you an issue, check your path.

For more information on this look into URL Encoding and Decoding:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx